# What is this <location> element referred to in <configSections><section> in app.config

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationsection

I'm creating a [ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx). In the example given the attribute `allowLocation` of the `<section>` attribute is set to `true`. Looking at [what this allowLocation means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/section-element), I am still puzzled. On that page is says `Determines whether the section can be used within the <location> element.`. I can not find documentation of this `<location>` element.

What does this `<location>` element do? What is it used for?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/b6x6shw7(v%3dvs.100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

> Specifies the resource that child configuration settings apply to and locks configuration settings, preventing the settings from being overridden by child configuration files.

And

> The location element can enclose other elements, either to apply configuration settings to a specific resource or to lock the configuration settings.

**Example:**

```
<configuration>
 <location path="Logon.aspx">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
</configuration>
```

[Source @ msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/b6x6shw7(v%3dvs.100))